# Refactoring mongoose schema using interface wont accept default value

Tags: node.js, mongoose, interface, mongoose-schema

It is not so easy to refactor mongoose schema into an interface:

It works:

```
const MySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  rating: Number,
  timestamp: { type: Date, default: Date.now() }, // no problem here
});
```

But refactoring into an interface:

```
interface IMySchema  {
  rating: Number,
  timestamp: { type: Date, default: Date.now() }, // problem here
}
const MySchema = new mongoose.Schema<IMySchema>();
```

Says:

> error TS4033: Property 'timestamp' of exported interface has or is using private name 'Date'.

Also - VS shows an additional error message

> Date only refers to a type but is being used as a namespace here

I wonder how to solve this problem... Any idea?

Comment: You can't replace schema with interface. Typescript doesn't exist at runtime. https://mongoosejs.com/docs/typescript.html

Answer (score 0):

Follow this guide [Separate document interface definition](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/typescript/schemas.html#separate-document-interface-definition):

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

interface MyDocument {
    rating?: number;
    timestamp?: Date;
}
const MySchema = new mongoose.Schema<MyDocument>({
    rating: Number,
    timestamp: { type: Date, default: Date.now() }, // no problem here
});

const Model = mongoose.model<MyDocument>('model', MySchema);

const doc = new Model();
doc.rating; // ok
doc.timestamp; // ok
```